# How to pass multiple checkbox values to Wordpress Search? custom_tax[]=val1&custom_tax[]=val2

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build a custom search form in Wordpress where the user would be able to select custom taxonomies to filter the posts against.

I am unfortunately getting this warning:

`Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 5343`, which is this function:

```php
function wp_basename( $path, $suffix = '' ) {
    return urldecode( basename( str_replace( array( '%2F', '%5C' ), '/', urlencode( $path ) ), $suffix ) );
}
```

Here is my code of the form:

```php
<form action="/" method="get">
    <?php $post_type = !empty( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : 'company'; ?>
    <label for="search" class="block"><?php echo __('Search', 'mydomain'); ?>:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="post_type" value="company" <?php echo $post_type == 'company' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Companies</input>
    <input type="radio" name="post_type" value="auditor" <?php echo $post_type == 'auditor' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Auditors</input>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" class="block" placeholder="<?php echo __('Type here'); ?>" />
    <div>
        <?php $certificates = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => 'certificate',
                'hide_empty' => false
            ]); 
            foreach($certificates as $certificate) : 
        ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="certificate[]" id="certificate-<?php echo $certificate->slug; ?>" value="<?php echo $certificate->slug; ?>" <?php echo (!empty($_GET['certificate']) && in_array($certificate->slug, $_GET['certificate']) ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> <?php echo $certificate->name; ?>
        <?php       
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo pll_current_language(); ?>" name="lang" id="lang" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('Search'); ?>" />
</form>
```

and this is how I attempt to see the search results:

`http://wordpress.local/?post_type=auditor&s=&certificate%5B%5D=iso-22000&certificate[]=iso-9001`

Any ideas how to bypass this warning and still submit the checkboxes as an array? (custom_tax[])